# terraform alicloud failed to create alicloud_cs_managed_kubernetes

Tags: terraform, alibaba-cloud

I'm using terraform to create Ali cloud managed kubernetes. the link I'm following is below:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/alicloud/r/cs_managed_kubernetes.html

I'm using exact same code as terraform states. The Available zone I'm using is `cn-shenzhen-a`, however, when I run `terraform apply`, I'm always getting this error

```
alicloud_cs_managed_kubernetes.k8s: [ERROR] terraform-provider-alicloud/alicloud/resource_alicloud_cs_managed_kubernetes.go:322: Resource alicloud_cs_managed_kubernetes CreateKubernetesCluster Failed!!! [SDK denverdino/aliyungo ERROR]:
Aliyun API Error: RequestId: C598AA1D-6993-46F6-A831-A9A6E8B8CEC1 Status Code: 400 Code: ZoneNotSupported Message: The current zone  does not support creating SLB, please try other zones

Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with
any resources that successfully completed. Please address the error
above and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure.
```

I have double checked the SLB and found `cn-shenzhen-a` can create SLB. 
the Ali cloud account I'm using is china account not international account.

Answer (score 0):

you should create vpc & vswitch early, setting vswitch_ids in k8s config.
it resolve same problem in my environment.

```
data "alicloud_vswitches" "vswitch"{

}
resource "alicloud_cs_managed_kubernetes" "k8s" {
  ......
  vswitch_ids = [data.alicloud_vswitches.vswitch.vswitches[0].id]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it by specifying vswitch_ids instead of availability_zone:

```
resource "alicloud_cs_managed_kubernetes" "k8s" {
  name              = "${var.name}"
  # availability_zone = "cn-beijing-c"
  vswitch_ids = ["vsw-2ze........."]
  # availability_zone     = "${data.alicloud_zones.main.zones.2.id}"
  new_nat_gateway       = true
 ...
```

Refer the following link:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-alicloud/issues/1097#issuecomment-555897474